# flutter layout in singlechildscrollview

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have the below layout and want to push CustomPaints at the end of the page for any screen size, how to achieve that? I tried `Spacer` but got an error and tried `Flexible` but I don't know how to use them properly.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const HeaderShape(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            body,
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    painter: const FooterPainter1(),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  CustomPaint(
                    painter: const FooterPainter2(),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not use spacer in a column widget, if you did not wrap your column widget with a container/sizedBox with a definite height.

Flexible widget will wrap your widget to take the available space of the parent widget, but will NOT force the child to fit the space.

Expanded will share the available space of the parent widget, and force the child widget to change its width/height to fill the available space.

So, wraping you column with a sizedbox with height and using spacer widget will help you to achieve what you are looking for. Check the code below:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -kToolbarHeight - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(child: Text('My Header')),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(child: Text('My Body')),
              Spacer(),
              Container(child: Text('My Footer')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

If you are not using appbar in your page, just remove kToolbarHeight and MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top from your SizedBox height parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but for the small screen, I got overflowed error and the page did not scroll on small screens.

Comment: Please add your header, body, Footerpainter1 and footerpainter2 code.

Comment: In what device are you getting the error?

Comment: I've got on the web when I tried to test the page on a small screen I couldn't scroll the page. I need scroll functionality and a fixed footer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: As I dont have your footer widget, I can not simply say why you are getting the error. If you run my above code, you will see no errors at all.

Comment: footer is a `SizedBox` with a height of 150. Thanks for your explanation.